# In Marvel Comics, what material is the strap on Thor's hammer made of?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel

We all know the hammer is made from uru and was forged in the heart of a star. But what about the leather strap?

Has this ever been addressed?

Comment: I removed last part of the last sentence, otherwise it'd become opinion based question which isn't allowed here.

Comment: The marvel wiki says that it's enchanted to be unbreakable but is made of common leather. No citation though...

Comment: It's called a thong, which is commonly referred to as leather but I couldn't find it being called a leather thong.

Comment: @Edlothiad Searching for information on Thor's thong has given a lot of interesting information, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strapping around the handle (and the thong, which seems to be a part of the strapping) are leather. Whether this is mundane cow-hide or something [more exotic](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/hnQ8jP5pTu04R_DlU7zSw5Iey9iCmUXo6A2Ubij7OTb8fDHsNgtcRXHyxffStI5zfpaKlaNYqKNG_S1l9WrU-0jCW0K4454FeWWyeCvdMpy23eRtj0TfzS2v6OCq_5BIfN3Y9Q=s0) isn't stated but we do know it has magical enchantments upon it.

[image]

[image]

In earlier serials, the thong was described as "unbreakable"

[image]

[image]

Namor begs to differ. The leather thong at the base of the handle has been cut *by a magical object* on at least one occasion.

[image]

Comment: Thor can see becauss of his baby-blue Asgardian eyes. Naturally. Did the writer just have a crush on Thor, or did they think that blue eyes are better for seeing underwater?